# Why do I get the error "Received usmStatsUnknownUserNames.0 Report-PDU with value 1" when I try to connect to my device using Net::SNMP?

Tags: linux, perl, snmp, net-snmp

I am trying to write a Perl script to do an SNMP get. It should work like the following command:

```sh
snmpget -v 3 -l authNoPriv -a MD5 -u V3User -A V3Password 10.0.1.203 sysUpTime.0
```

Returns:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysUpTime.0 = Timeticks: (492505406) 57 days, 0:04:14.06
```

But my Perl script returns the following:

```
ERROR: Received usmStatsUnknownUserNames.0 Report-PDU with value 1 during synchronization.
```

Last but not least, here is the Perl script:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Net::SNMP;

my $desc = 'sysUpTime.0';

my ($session, $error) = Net::SNMP->session(
   -hostname     => '10.0.1.202',
   -version      => 'snmpv3',
   -username     => 'V3User',
   -authprotocol => 'md5',
   -authpassword => 'V3Password'
);

if (!defined($session)) {
      printf("ERROR: %s.\n",  $error);
      exit 1;
}
my $response = $session->get_request($desc);
my %pdesc = %{$response};

my $err = $session->error;
if ($err){
   return 1;
}
print %pdesc;
exit 0;
```

I called the Perl script and `snmpget` on the same (Linux) machine. What could be causing this and how can I fix it?

Comment: You can check this similar question:[SNMP V3 and Perl][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25374612/snmp-v3-and-perl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your script I noticed that hostname value has 10.0.1.**202**

but the snmpget command you're using has 10.0.1.**203**

wrong IP by any chance?

Comment: That's it. Shame on me :/ Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3):

As [PrgmError points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28241741/176646), you're using a different IP address in your Perl script than in your `snmpget` command; I would double check that. The particular error you're getting indicates that your username is wrong; if the IP mismatch was simply a typo in your question, I would double check the username next.

A few other points about your Perl script:

### Use `die`

You should use `die` instead of `printf` and `exit` since `die` will print the line number where it was invoked. This will make debugging your script much easier if there are multiple places it could fail:

```
die "Error: $error" if not defined $session;
```

will print something like

```
Error: foo bar at foo.pl line 17.
```

Also, using `return` inside an `if` statement doesn't make any sense; I think you meant to use

```
if ($err) {
    exit 1;
}
```

but you should `die` with the specific error message you get instead of silently failing:

```
die $err if $err;
```

### Fix arguments to `get_request`

Your invocation of the `get_request` method looks wrong. According to the [docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP#get_request---send-a-SNMP-get-request-to-the-remote-agent), you should be calling it like this:

```
my $response = $session->get_request(-varbindlist => [ $oid ]);
```

Note that `Net::SNMP` only works with numeric OIDs, so you'll have to change `sysUpTime.0` to `1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0`.

Comment: That's it. Shame on me :/ Thanks for you help!